# How to use .get to get a random value from a dictionary command?

Tags: python

I'm testing out with `.get` and see if its use is more viable than my other methods. In any case I'd like to learn it. The current code returns:

```py
None None
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? And is there an issue where I can use something else besides `.get` to solve?

Here's my code:

```
x = dict(ice_cream_flavors = ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Cookie-dough', 'Mint-choclate', 'Rainbow'],
         ice_cream_cones_flavors = ['vanilla-cone', 'chocolate-cone','cookie-dough-cone', 'mint-cone', 'rainbow-cone'])

y = x.get(random.choice(x['ice_cream_flavors']))
z = x.get(random.choice(x['ice_cream_cones_flavors']))

print(y, z)
```

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: When you do `random.choice(x['ice_cream_flavors'])` you get one of the flavors, for example `Vanilla`. Then, you use this value to access the dict with `get`. But the dict only has two keys: `ice_cream_flavors ` and `ice_cream_cones_flavors `. So `get` returns the default which is `None`

Comment: More viable than your other methods _for accomplishing what_? Tools are useful for specific purposes. This code doesn't showcase a good reason to use `get` (instead of just doing a `__getitem__`-type `x['ice_cream_flavors']` direct lookup), but that doesn't mean good reasons don't exist.

Comment: *"Is there something I'm doing wrong?"* - how can we know? You didn't even specify what you're actually trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is not correct as you use 'get' in order to get some value from a list. You should use the following instead, in order to get a random value from each dict['value']/list:

```
y=random.choice(x.get('ice_cream_flavors'))
z=random.choice(x.get('ice_cream_cones_flavors'))

print(y, z)
#Chocolate vanilla-cone
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to fetch random elements from given lists, don't use `get`; it's a fail-safe look-up, but `choice` won't fail on this data.

Your problem is that you use `choice` to get a flavor.  Then you use `get` to look up that flavor in your dict.  There is no such entry, merely the two named lists.  Instead, stop when you get that flavor:

```
y = random.choice(x['ice_cream_flavors'])
z = random.choice(x['ice_cream_cones_flavors'])

print(y, z)
```

Sample output:

```
Rainbow vanilla-cone
```